# Asynchronous IO in Node.js fails to update reference in object

Tags: node.js, asynchronous, fs, async.js

I've simplified my issue to the following:

```
var fs = require("fs");
var async = require("async");


var myReport;

function Report() {

    this.report = null;

}

Report.prototype.initializeReport = function(callback) {    

    fs.readFile("./scrape reports/Scrape Report 1522604653782", "utf-8", function(err, data) {

        this.report = JSON.parse(data);
        console.log("Found this report: " + this.report);

        callback();
    });

}

module.exports = function() {

    myReport = new Report();

    myReport.initializeReport(function() {
        console.log(myReport.report);
    });
};
```

When I run this, the output is the following:

```
> Found this report: [object Object]
> null
```

The function initializeReport() is able to fetch the JSON, but any attempts to reference myReport.report later on only gets null, as if it were never assigned.

Why is this happening?

Comment: Before finding the answer lets find the intention. Why you are doing that when you can just pass the result instead of referencing the object. Is there any specific reason for that? @colinrob

Comment: This is just a simplified version of the problem from a much larger complex program, much of which relies on instances of the "Report" object. Each Report object needs a reference to a JSON object that's read from the filesystem.

Comment: ok, I gave you the answer. Let me know if you need more clarification.

Comment: updated the answer with the possible solution. @colinrob

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your `fs.readFile` function response `this.report` is not actually pointing to `myReport` object. So, you have never assigned to `myReport.report` property after initiating it with `null`.

Quick solution can be:

just assign to `myReport.report` instead of `this.report`

Alternative solution can be:

you can bind the context of a function using `bind` or `apply` function of javascript.

Comment: Thank you, the problem was that `this` was redefined during the filesystem calls, so you're right, I was never assigning to it.

However there was no need to use bind or apply, and assigning to 'myReport.report' wouldn't be viable if multiple instances of the object were needed, so instead I just added 
    `var thisReport = this;`
to the top of Report.initializeReport, before the filesystem calls, and assigned values to `thisReport.report`.

Comment: yeah, whichever fits in your use case. As you have not mentioned the actual use case on the question, it was impossible to suggest a solution to your need. @colinrob